# Pagination for only one partial view in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, pagination

I have viewmodel with 3 classes

```
    public IEnumerable<Nazivi_grupa> ngrupa { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Grupe_radova> gradova { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Pozicije> pozicije { get; set; }
```

partial view partPozicijeView.cshtml

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<WebApplication3.ViewModels.mainViewModel>
@using PagedList.Mvc;

@{ some code to show table }
```

and main view index.cshtml

```
@model WebApplication3.ViewModels.mainViewModel
@using PagedList.Mvc;
    <tr>
        <td>Category&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;:</td>
        <td><div id="KnjigeNormativa">@Html.Partial("partKnjigeNormativaView", Model)</div> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sub - Category&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;:</td>
        <td><div id="GrupeRadova"> @Html.Partial("partGrupeRadovaView", Model)</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Products&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;:</td>
        <td><div id="Pozicije"> @Html.Partial("partPozicijeView", Model)</div></td>
    </tr>
```

that calls 3 partial views to show first 2 tables in cascaded dropdowns and 3rd one (pozicije) in a table.

Now i'm trying to add pagination to that table, but no matter what, i'm getting an error

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'WebApplication3.ViewModels.mainViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'PagedList.IPagedList`1[WebApplication3.ViewModels.mainViewModel]'.
```

on 3rd partial view call.

Here's also code for controller

```
    public ActionResult SelectPozicije(string SelectedPosId, int? pnum)
    {


        int pageNumber = (pnum ?? 1);

        mainViewModel mv = new mainViewModel();
        mv.pozicije = new List<Pozicije>();

//            mv.pozicije = (from p in mainViewModel.getPozicije()
//                           where p.grupa == SelectedPosId
//                           select p).ToPagedList(pageNumber, 25);
        mv.pozicije = (from p in mainViewModel.getPozicije()
                       where p.grupa == SelectedPosId
                       select p).ToList();


        return PartialView("partPozicijeView", mv);
    }
```

I tried (commented code) to return .ToPagedList() but no success...

can someone point me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
//your main model
namespace WebApplication3.ViewModels
{
public class mainViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Nazivi_grupa> ngrupa { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Grupe_radova> gradova { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Pozicije> pozicije { get; set; }
}
}
```

your main view

```
//your main view Index.cshtml
@model WebApplication3.ViewModels.mainViewModel
<tr>
    <td>Category&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;:</td>
    <td><div id="KnjigeNormativa">@Html.Partial("partKnjigeNormativaView", Model.ngrupa)</div> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Sub - Category&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;:</td>
    <td><div id="GrupeRadova"> @Html.Partial("partGrupeRadovaView", Model.gradova)</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Products&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;:</td>
    <td><div id="Pozicije"> @Html.Partial("partPozicijeView", Model.pozicije)</div></td>
</tr>
```

your main controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string SelectedPosId, int? page)
{
int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
mainViewModel mv = new mainViewModel();
mv.ngrupa = //code for ngrupa list
mv.gradova = //code for ngrupa list
mv.pozicije = (from p in mainViewModel.getPozicije()
               where p.grupa == SelectedPosId
               order by p.id //order column here
               select p).ToPagedList(pageNumber, 25);
return View(mv);
}
```

your partial view

```
//your paged partial view partPozicijeView.cshtml
@model PagedList.IPagedList<WebApplication3.ViewModels.Pozicije>
@using PagedList.Mvc;

@{ some code to show table }
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.ResultsPage,


page => Url.Action("Index", "ControllerName", new { SelectedPosId = YourPosId, page = page},PagedListRenderOptions.PageNumbersOnly)
```

Comment: I don't have ViewModels.Pozicije declared as separate class. This is just a property inside mainViewModel class.

Comment: you have declared this pozicije property in mainViewModel but this is the list of Pozicije i.e. `IEnumerable<Pozicije>` where `Pozicije` should be a class delared

Comment: it's a separate model for table from database.
main viewmodel uses that 3 tables to show 2 dropdowns and a table that need to be paginated.

Comment: ok use the table name in your partial view
`@model PagedList.IPagedList<Pozicije>`

Comment: IT's not exactly answer i was looking for, but you helped a lot. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public ActionResult SelectPozicije(string SelectedPosId, int? pnum)
{
    int pageNumber = (pnum ?? 1);

    mainViewModel mv = new mainViewModel();
    mv.pozicije = new List<Pozicije>();
    mv.pozicije = (from p in mainViewModel.getPozicije()
                   where p.grupa == SelectedPosId
                   select p).ToList();

   if (mv.pozicije.Count() != 0)
   {
      var resultsPage = mv.pozicije.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 20);
      ViewBag.ResultsPage = resultsPage;
      return PartialView("partPozicijeView", mv);
   }
   else
   {
      return PartialView("partPozicijeView");
   }
}
```

Then in the view:

```
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.ResultsPage,
                      page => Url.Action("SelectPozicije", "ControllerName", new { SelectedPosId = YourPosId, pnum = page}, 
                      PagedListRenderOptions.PageNumbersOnly)
```

Modify what needs to be modified accordingly. Hope it helps.

Comment: It's same error... I think this has something with model declaration in my partial view cshtml being different from declaration in index.cshtml

@model PagedList.IPagedList<WebApplication3.ViewModels.mainViewModel>

Comment: Yes that should be the issue. Please show the PartialView code as well

Comment: I don't think PV code is important, it's just foreach that put's data in <table><tr><td> tags. It don't even get executed when i start application. Error is thrown when "        <td><div id="Pozicije"> @Html.Partial("partPozicijeView", Model)</div></td>
" is called for first time...

Comment: Does changing the line to `IEnumerable<WebApplication3.ViewModels.mainViewModel>` help?

Comment: Thanks Dude ..you saved my day, I was struggling with the same issue..and your answer helped a lot.